# (Mahjong) What does this sentence mean: 対局の間一度も飛ばされない

Tags: translation, jargon

I am playing a japanese Riichi Mahjong game. There is a quest ingame which I can't understand.

3対局の間一度も飛ばされない

Google translate tells me I have to "never get blown during a game" and I guess I have to do it 3 times. But what does it mean in regards to Riichi Mahjong?

To never get 'Ron' (playing the winning tile for another player)?
To never let another player steal from me?
To not lose the round?
To not lose the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it means to never get run out in the game. In Japanese Mahjong there is a rule in which if your score gets to negative the game ends. It is called "Running out".